# "You do not have permission to access this page" on a CiviContribute confirmation page

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute

I have a totally standard CiviContribute page on a system running CiviCRM 5.27.2 on top of WordPress. "Allow other amounts" is true. Minimum amount: $5. The default amount is also $5. Here's the behaviour I've noticed:

- if I enter an extra amount of $5 and enter my credit card info then I get a permission denied page with the following backtrace:

```
or::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /home/ontar026/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(39): CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(CR
M_Core_Exception))
#2 /home/ontar026/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1535): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#3 /home/ontar026/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke(Object(WP))
#4 /home/ontar026/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, (Array:1))
#5 /home/ontar026/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(551): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#6 /home/ontar026/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php(758): do_action_ref_array("wp", (Array:1))
#7 /home/ontar026/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php(1291): WP->main("")
#8 /home/ontar026/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(16): wp()
#9 /home/ontar026/public_html/index.php(17): require("/home/ontar026/public_html/wp-blog-header.php")
#10 {main}
```

- if I enable a confirmation page then it works fine for extra amount of $5
- if I have no extra amount then it works fine

Of course all of this doesn't happen in test mode.

The permission that's failing is "access CiviCRM".

Any ideas on why this is happening?